# How to express working shifts in perfect English

Tags: grammaticality, british-english

Suppose we want to work in day shift for two days. How will you express it in correct English? Can I say:

> We will be working in day shift for two days (Monday and Tuesday).

Would that be perfect English?

Comment: Idiomatic usage here in the North of England, at least, would be 'We'll be working days next Monday and Tuesday.' More formal but also quite acceptable: 'We'll be working the day shift next Monday and Tuesday.' What look like direct objects here ('days' and 'the day shift') are better considered as adverbials.

Comment: can I say coming Monday and Tuesday?

Comment: In AmE, at least, you don't work "in day shift" but "on the day shift".

Answer (score 2):

I'd say, "We will be working the day shift Monday and Tuesday."

You don't "work in a shift", you just "work a shift".

I see Peter Shor and JR both say "work on the day shift". Hmm. I don't recall hearing people use "on" in there, just "work the day shift". I just did a Google ngram and it found "work the day shift" used four times as often as "work on the day shift". (It also found zero uses of "work in the day shift".) However, it shows "work on the day shift" as more popular up to about 1970. This appears to be a changing usage.

Comment: As a footnote, my last suggestion agrees with what you say: in other words, in "We're working days next Monday and Tuesday," "days" = "a shift", as "days" is the name of the shift. So, I agree that the preposition is optional, depending on how it's worded.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, "perfect" doesn't seem like the right word to use. There's usually more than one valid way to say something in English, and one isn't any more "perfect" than the other. For example, you could start your sentence with any of these (they are all perfectly valid):

> - "We will be working..."
> - "We will work..."
> - "We are scheduled to work..."

You could continue with either of these:

> - "during the day shift,"
> - "on the day shift"

and then conclude with:

> - "for two days (Monday and Tuesday)."
> - "over the next two days (Monday and Tuesday)."
> - "next Monday and Tuesday."

Those components could form up to 18 different sentences, and I think all of them would sound just fine.

Moreover, with more context, you needn't be so wordy. Assuming an employer has three standard shifts (Day, Swing, and Night), and the conversation has already established the context, one could simply say:

> - We're working days next Monday and Tuesday.

and there would be nothing wrong with that, either.

Comment: We're going to work the day shift...

Comment: @Bob: That one works, too. By no means should my 19 sentences be considered an exhaustive list.

Comment: Just thought I'd throw in a "gonna" example.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You *could* replace 'next' by 'the coming' (not just 'coming'). But if we're talking about *a few days from* now rather than *a few days on from January 1st*, say, I'd stick with 'next'.